# Parsing big amount of HTML data and store it in DB

Tags: python, database, multithreading, python-3.x, dictionary

I need to parse about 5.000.000 records (users data) from a web page. I wrote a python function and I'm getting every record as a dictionary. Example output:

```
{'key1': 'value1', 'key2': ['value2'], 'key3:': ['value3a', 'value3b'], 'key4': value4}
```

It's dictionary so of course it's unordered but what's worse - keys are not fixed. I can get output like this too:

```
{'key2': ['value2'], 'key3:': ['value3a', 'value3b', 'value3c', 'value3d'], 'key4': value4}
```

or

```
{'key3:': ['value3a'], 'key4': value4}
```

or event just an empty dictionary `{}`. So it could be a dictionary with normal key-values pairs, key-values where values is a list or just an empty dictionary. No dictionary in dictionary, tuples, etc.

Now, I want to store every record in a data base. One problem is that getting whole data will take about 30 days so I use 5 threads ('only' 6 days now ;) ) which runs my get_data parsing function:

```
threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(userId1, userId120)).start()
threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(userId120, userId125)).start()
threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(userId100, userId150)).start()
threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(userId150, userId200)).start()
threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(userId200, userId250)).start()
```

I didn't use any DB before, so I don't want to wait 6 days and do whole process in a wrong way. As an output I would like to get a database like:

```
 key1  |  key2  |      key3
------------------------------------
value1 | value2 | (value3a,value3b)
 NULL  | value2 | (value3a,..,..,..)
 NULL  |  NULL  |      NULL
```

where the `(value3a,value3b)` is store in one cell but with direct access to any of value in that list.

So my question is: what database should I use to store data as I need to and how to deal with multithreading, not fixed amount of keys and a few values in a one cell?

Comment: What about using `scrapy` - it is based on `twisted` and has a concept of database pipelines. Sounds like a good use case for your task.

Comment: Thanks for a nice comment. I'll use scrapy in the future projects, but now I would have to get rid of whole beautifulsoup parser and I don't want to do this this time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `multiprocessing.Pool` -- it's easy to fire up N workers and submit a long list of jobs for them to run. The `threading` library is fun but is lower-level and harder to use.

Any classical SQL or NoSQL database will be able to handle your requirements.  Sqlite3 is the easiest, but it's mostly used via a single thread, so I don't recommend for this application. MySQL or Postgres or MongoDB will be fine.  Since you're not processing money, the latter might be easiest, as it's very fast and flexible and easy to start with.

Have fun!

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I've just installed pymongo and will try to use multiprocessing.Pool :)

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of PostgreSQL have some "No-SQL" features that can handle your list-valued columns, in various ways: as key/value stores, as JSON data, as arrays. It can index within the values, as well. These features are only in the latest versions of the DBMS (9.2 somewhat, more so in the current 9.3, still more in the upcoming 9.4).

Typically (99% of postgres users, and in any other relational dbms) you would **not** store the data this way. Rather, you'd *normalize* the data (UNfactor the lists) so that every row has at most one value in each column. In the relational model, aggregating those values is the job of queries, e.g. using the GROUP BY clause in SQL.

Comment: The problem is all that values are related to the location. It could be (Europe, France, Paris) or just (Paris) or (Paris, France) etc. I think I'll just group that and make `location1`,`location2`,`location3` columns. Thanks for helpful answer :)

Comment: After creating a database in MongoDB without normalizing the data from the list I'm bit of confused why I should do that if searching in that lists is very fast.

Comment: > "I'm bit of confused why I should do that"

Normalize the data, you mean?

Comment: Exactly. I like it is stored as a list (array in MongoDB), because it's more readable for me and still fast (I guess).